# Trying to echo out every name in database table inside hrml list

Tags: php, sql

I have been trying to echo out database data through a while loop now for awhile but it doesn't work, I can't find where the issue is. I have tried echoing out data manually and that works just fine.

```
<?php $results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY id DESC"); ?>


<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) : ?>
   <li>
       <?php echo $row['message']; ?>
   </li>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: any error message?

Comment: nope I get nothing

Comment: So if your provided code works, what is the issue?

Comment: it doesn't work thats the thing, nothing happends, it is almost like $row doesn't exist

Comment: So what if you add in echo "hello<br>"; inside the while loop... Does that appear? Put it after the echo $row. Put another echo something after it... Does that show? This is Just to test that the code is running...

Comment: For good measure to see if you are getting any results quickly and to see what your query is returning - add in a var_dump($row) does that show anything?

Comment: I tried adding a bunch of echos and only the ones outside of the while loop works, var_dump didn't return anything either

Comment: So your error is in the while loop and your query isn't working...Ok well dont stop there, what does a var_dump($result); just after you set it, show you? I'd be suspicious of $con, can you echo that and view it...

Comment: the var_dump then returns object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(7) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Have you got error reporting enabled... and oldie but a goodie - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings

Comment: Ok, if you have phpmyadmin or something you can run SQL statements against your database, what does SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY id DESC give you?

Comment: I might be stupid or something but what do you mean exactly? I just started with sql and php

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you are connected to the database. I don't know if you omitted that on purpose or not. Also, check if the connection is established.

```
<?php

//Insert your server info here
$servername = "servername";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test_database";

// Create and check your connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<li>' . row["message"] . '</li>';
    }
} else {
    // Your query produced 0 results
    echo "Empty result!";
}

// Remember to close the connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```